# Prevent Cron from running multiple times Rails Loadbalancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron

I have a question, I have a load balancer and two instances of my web app up with cronjobs running in the background. How can I make sure in Rails that the cronjob only runs once in between the two instances?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to have the cron on both app servers? Why not just have one worker server?

If you can't just have one server where the job runs, you could probably save a value to the database indicating whether the job has been run or not and just look at that value before performing the job, so something like:

```
class BackgroundJob
  def perform
    return if performed_today?
    JobRun.create!(performed_on: Date.today)
    # Perform the job here
  end

  private

  def performed_today?
    JobRun.where(performed_on: Date.today).exists?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Manuel. I was learning towards that route of having one worker server, but I believe because for the purpose of keeping both servers the same, we wanted a better solution like the one you proposed.